# tha data dosent appear and i have only whitescreen

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i build a chat app and i try to call data from firebase to appear on the screen but only white screen appear iam still learning flutter and use firestore_cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKjrI.png)

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

 class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('chats/lTHEN8VkO7uVAtbeY25R/messeges');
 return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: users.snapshots(),
    builder: (ctx, code) {
      if (code.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
       }
        final documents = code.data.documents;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
          child: Text(documents[index]['text']),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        ),
        itemCount: documents.length,
        );
       },
       ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
     onPressed: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
    }
    }
```

Comment: the console page : W/DynamiteModule( 9021): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 9021): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 9021): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('chats/lTHEN8VkO7uVAtbeY25R/messeges');
 class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
 return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: users.snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
          snapshots.hasData) {
        print(snapshots.data);
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
           var doc=snapshots.data[index];
            Map data= doc.data; // this is your data which is probably a map
            return Text(
              data[index]['text']
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
       },
       ),
      
    );
    }
    }
```

Comment: same result  and this my console page

Comment: W/DynamiteModule( 9021): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 9021): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 9021): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.